# How did Clara get back to Trenzalore the first time?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-who

In the **Time of the Doctor** context, did she do that by holding on to the outer edge of the *TARDIS* and travel through time and space that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Clara hung onto the key and outside of the TARDIS. The TARDIS extended a field, I recall the Doctor saying, to protect her.

The TARDIS, did not want Jack Harkness to hang on to it, it tried to throw him off.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap. Well, that's what the Doctor said and what we obviously saw.... Didn't this kill Captain Jack Harkness though when he did it before? The 50th and Christmas special episode destroyed a lot of important things in my opinion.

Comment: Ha, but the journey was much more of a trial for Jack Harkness. The TARDIS tried to shake him off, and that's why it travelled 100,000,000,000,000 years into the future (sorry if I missed a couple of zeroes). That's quite a long way. In Time Of The Doctor, it was just a simple trip.